# setting the session timeout in shiro.ini file is giving warning

Tags: java, shiro

i am using shiro1.2.2 and i want to configure session time out in shiro.in file. i configure but it will giving warning and the session timeout is not set. 
the  warning is

```
 WARNING: The 'sessionMode' property has been deprecated.  Please configure an appropriate          WebSessionManager instance instead of using this property.  This property/method will be removed in a later version.
```

my shiro.ini file

```
 sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager 
 securityManager.sessionMode=native 
 securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 6000 
 securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

i dont know why this giving warning .

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Native-session-management-for-web-sessions-td7577474.html)?

Comment: i check..but its some other  problem

Comment: oh i got solution...the shiro-1.2.2 after no need to used sessionMode property..i remove then its now its working fine.if we will used then it will giving warning and its want be set timeout